# ggplot2 line and dot, auto zero value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to draw a line plot using **ggplot2** consisting of multiple lines grouped according to a particular column value in my data frame. However, there exists occasions where there is no point for a x-axis value, I would like to assign zero y-axis value to such occasions such that each line have points for every x-axis value.

Suppose I have a data.frame, df

```
  number value      state
1      1     4 California
2      2     1    Arizona
3      3     5 California
4      4     5    Arizona
5      5     2     Alaska
6      6     3    Arizona
```

where column number is the factor data type.

And I would like to draw a line plot x-axis = number, y-axis = value, and grouped by state. 
For this example,

```
number value      state
1          4 California
3          5 California
```

the line for california will only connect between and 1 and 3 skipping 2 and not continuing till 6.

Comment: Are you trying to add zeros to your data frame and then plot the results? What  do you mean then by 'the line will only connect between 1 and 3, skipping 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dataframe with zeros and merge

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame("number"=c(1:6), value=c(4,1,5,5,2,3), state=c("California", "Arizona", "California", "Arizona", "Alaska", "Arizona")) %>% 
   tbl_df()

states = unique(df$state)
numbers = unique(df$number)

df2 = data.frame(state = sort(rep(states, length(numbers))),
                 number = rep(numbers, length(states)))

pd = df2 %>%
  merge(df, all=T) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value),0,value))

plot1 = ggplot(pd, aes(number, value, colour=state)) + 
  geom_line(size=2)+
  geom_point(size=5)

plot(plot1)
ggsave(filename = "plot.png", plot = plot1)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
ggplot(x, aes(number, value, colour=state)) + 
  geom_line(size=2) + geom_point(size=5)
```

[image]